# MVC "Write-Once" Fields in Model and View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I want DRY/reuse as much editor code (View and Model) as possible. Some of my fields can only be set at creation, and never edited. Are there any pre-existing MVC/DataAnnotation features I should look at?

For example, maybe there is a data attribute that causes EditorFor to operate like DisplayFor if the value is non-null.

Model.cs

```
[Unchangeable]
string UserReferenceId { get; set; }

string Description { get; set; }
```

edit: to clarify my goal, I've added an answer with sample code for the approach I'm currently planning. If there's a better way/pre-existing feature for this, please let me know.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you are passing around data like that, why not use the `Session`?

Comment: @jonnyGold, We try to avoid using the Session unnecessarily in MVC.  They keep it buried deep inside of `TempData` in case we need it, but in general it's not really necessary if the system is modeled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both the `System.ComponentModel.ReadOnlyAttribute` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EditableAttribute` (I think `EditableAttribute` is .NET 4). When model metadata is created for properties marked with either of these, you can see `ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly` will be set correctly.

Frustratingly, however, the built-in editor templates will still show editable fields, even if `ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly` is `true`.

You can, however, create your own shared editor template for each data type where you want this metadata property respected, and handle it specifically.

**~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml**

```
@model String
@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly)
{
  @Html.Hidden(string.Empty, Model)
}
@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly ? Html.DisplayText(string.Empty) : Html.TextBox(string.Empty))
```

**View Model**

```
[Editable(false)]
public string UserReferenceId { get; set; }
```

You'll note that in the event the metadata for the model indicates IsReadOnly, I draw a hidden field. This is so the value of that property is persisted across posts.

If you don't want the field displayed at all, but persisted across posts, you can use `System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInputAttribute`. In this case, only the hidden is drawn.

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
public string UserReferenceId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Some of it is helpful to my intent, but I think mainly my intent was unclear. I want my user to be able to edit the value via the view, only until the data has been saved once. On following edits, sibling values can still be edited, but it cannot. As a side note, don't you allow users to bypass your "read-only business logic" by opening their browser's DOM inspector, by using a hidden field in this way? Thanks, Shannon

Comment: The situation you describe is usually solved by two different view models; one for Create and one for Edit. On the Edit view model, the display-only properties would have something like `Editable(false)` as described above. You then have two different rules for mapping FROM the view model TO the persistent entity: In the Edit view model, the values from the non-editable property is ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I could use two different view models and the same view, or conversely two different views and the same model. I had hoped there was a way a simple way to share the validation definitions and all else.

Comment: Polymorphism is your friend. Override Create and override the property you want uneditable, and add the `Editable` attribute to it. Then you need only one view (depending... I don't know what your view looks like)

Comment: Also, `EditableAttribute` has a property `AllowInitialValue`, which seems to be used for what you are describing. However, it is ignored by MVC (how can MVC know out of the box whether or not a model is a new record or not?). You could, of course, add this functionality to editor templates yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm thinking of implementing if nothing similar is pre-existing:

**EditableWhenNewModel.cs**

```
public class EditableWhenNewModel : IIsNew
{
    public bool IsNew { get { return recordId == 0; } }
    string UserReferenceId { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    public void Save(RepositoryItem record) {
        if (IsNew) { record.UserReferenceId = UserReferenceId; }
        record.Description = Description;
... etc.
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@model EditableWhenNewModel
@Html.EditorWhenNewFor(m => m.UserReferenceId)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)
```

**EditorWhenNewFor.cs**

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorWhenNewFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
) where TModel : IIsNew {
    return htmlHelper.ViewData.Model.IsNew ?
        htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression) :
        htmlHelper.DisplayFor(expression);
}
```